# Issues with defining a path for PHP include across multiple folders

Tags: php, path, absolute-path

cant figure out how to do what im trying.

I want a way to include PHP files so that i can call the same file from within any file in any level folder and it always points to the same files.

So i have a website setup e.g.

```
root
init.php
databaseconn.php
index.php
/css/
    main.css
/settings/
    user_profile.php
/template/
    sidebar.php
/includes/
    get_user.php
```

For example, on user_profile.php i am including the sidebar.php file.

For now i would use:

```
../template/sidebar.php
```

And then ../includes/get_user.php inside that sidebar file.

Which works fine. The problem however is that i also include the same sidebar.php file on my index.php page. This then causes the issues.

To counter this, i have tried this:

```
<?php
  $isDevelopment = true;
  $baseInclude = ($isDevelopment ? '//localhost/website/' : '//www.site.com/');
?>
```

And then when including any files across the site i have used:

```
include $baseInclude. 'template/sidebar.php';
```

When doing this however i am getting an error.

The error shows:

```
Warning: include(//localhost/website/template/sidebar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/settings/user_profile.php on line 46
```

I dont understand why its looking for the file inside the user_profile.php file when it shows and i have defined that its coing from the localhost path...

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you define the root path in your init.php via __DIR__ (not bold, the underscore crap - stupid stackoverflow formatting) and use relative paths to that defined constant

Comment: Apart from that: Including files over http is not going to work unless the include does not need any information from the calling script and does not return anything but html. The problem is that it will get processed separately in a different request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `init.php` file add this at the top

`define('ROOT', __DIR__);`

now in your other files use

`include (ROOT . '/full/path/to/file.php');`

in your code it would look like this

`include (ROOT . '/template/sidebar.php');`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
$baseInclude = getcwd();
```